# bash script to help identify files and path with a count sorted by day of the week recursivley

Tags: bash, unix

i'm not a script-er really (yet), so apologies in advance.

What I need to do is search a path for files within the last 7 days then count the number of files in each directrory for each day (Mon to sun) for each day for each directory.

so for eaxmple

From folder - Rootfiles

Directory 1 : 
Number of files Monday
Number of files ..n
Number of files Sunday
Directory 2 :
Number of files Monday
Number of files ..n
Number of files Sunday

So far I have this from my basic command line knowledge and a bit of research.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l {} \; | grep "^-" | awk '{
key=$6$7
freq[key]++
}
END {
for (date in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", date, freq[date]
}'
```

but a couple of problems, I need to print each directory then I need to figure out the Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday sort.

And for some reason works on my test folders with basic folders and names, but isn't on the production folders.

Even some pouinters of where to start thinking would be helpful

Thanks in advance all, you all awesome!

Neil

Comment: Do you *have* to use shell? I'd switch to a language like perl or python for anything non-trivial.

Comment: I'd second @NoufalIbrahim. Though I'd find that easier with Ruby ;)

Comment: yes for now i need to use bash :(

Comment: Actually, ive been told perl is fine, so I will probably move over as im more comfrtable in perl, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I found some addtional code that is helping

```
 #!bin/bash

# pass in the directory to search on the command line, use $PWD if not arg received
rdir=${1:-$(pwd)}

# if $rdir is a file, get it's directory
if [ -f $rdir ]; then
    rdir=$(dirname $rdir)
fi

# first, find our tree of directories
for dir in $( find $rdir -type d -print ); do
    # get a count of directories within $dir.
    sdirs=$( find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l );
    # only proceed if sdirs is less than 2 ( 1 = self ).
    if (( $sdirs < 2 )); then 
        # get a count of all the files in $dir, but not in subdirs of $dir)
        files=$( find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l ); 
        echo "$dir : $files"; 
    fi
done
```

if I could somehow replace the line

```
sdirs=$( find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l );
```

with my original code block that would help.

props to

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/counting-files-in-leaves-of-directory-tree

for that bit of code

Answer (score 1):

Neat problem.

I think in your `find` command you will want to add the `--time-style=+%w` to get the day of the week.

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l --time-style=+%w {} \;
```

I'm not sure why you are grepping for lines that start with a dash (since you're already only finding files.)  This is not necessary, so I would remove it.

Then I would get the directory names from this output by stripping the filenames, or everything after the last slash from each line.

```
| sed -e 's:/[^/]*$:/:'
```

Then I would cut out all the tokens before the day of the week.  Since you're using `.` as the starting point, you can expect each directory to start with `./`.

```
| sed -e 's:.*\([0-6]\) \./:\1 ./:'
```

From here you can `sort -k2` to sort by directory name and then day of the week.

Eventually you can pipe this into `uniq -c` to get the counts of days per week by directory, but I would convert it to human readable days first.

```
| awk '
  /^0/ { $1 = "Monday   " }
  /^1/ { $1 = "Tuesday  " }
  /^2/ { $1 = "Wednesday" }
  /^3/ { $1 = "Thursday " }
  /^4/ { $1 = "Friday   " }
  /^5/ { $1 = "Saturday " }
  /^6/ { $1 = "Sunday   " }
  { print $0 }
'
```

Putting this all together:

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l --time-style=+%w {} \; \
  | sed -e 's:/[^/]*$:/:' \
  | sed -e 's:.*\([0-6]\) \./:\1 ./:' \
  | sort -k2 \
  | awk '
  /^0/ { $1 = "Monday   " }
  /^1/ { $1 = "Tuesday  " }
  /^2/ { $1 = "Wednesday" }
  /^3/ { $1 = "Thursday " }
  /^4/ { $1 = "Friday   " }
  /^5/ { $1 = "Saturday " }
  /^6/ { $1 = "Sunday   " }
  { print $0 }
' | uniq -c
```

On my totally random `PWD` it looks like this:

```
  1 Monday    ./
  1 Tuesday   ./
  5 Saturday  ./
  2 Sunday    ./
 17 Monday    ./M3Javadoc/
  1 Thursday  ./M3Javadoc/
  1 Saturday  ./M3Javadoc/
  1 Sunday    ./M3Javadoc/
```